# get distinct user rows from table while counting a different row

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, where-clause

I am trying to count rows from a SQL Table named "reports", sorted by "working" being 0 / 1 / 2.

Currently I have this SQL query which works okay to give me three rows, each with a counter of how many there are that had "working" as either 0 / 1 / 2.

```
SELECT `working`, COUNT(`working`) AS `total` FROM `reports` 
WHERE `appid` = 379720 
GROUP BY `working` 
ORDER BY `report_id` DESC LIMIT 30
```

So it currently (correctly as per the SQL) gives me something like:

| Working | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 18 |

What I **want** to do though, is have only **one** row per user counted, which I can't quite wrap my head around. I can't use a distinct select on an "author_id" field as that ends up included and I can't group by it since I need it grouped by the working int.

To be clear: I want the same results display, but only count one per unique "author_id" from each row.

Any pointers?

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: How can I provide the sample data for something like MySQL? Added results as table.

Comment: You can share your data as `create table` and `inserts` statements, or as tabular text. More importantly, please show us the result that you want (as tabular text). You have only showed the current results.

Comment: The results format would be exactly the same, with the TOTAL field being different because I only want unique "author_id" rows counted.

Comment: Where does author_id come from ? and what does your desired result look like?   and why  one row per user counted then talk about author_id ? Question is quite garbled adding sample data and expect output as text to the question would help clarify.

Comment: `ORDER BY report_id` must cause an error, because there is no such column in output list. If `report_id` is a column of the table and no error message then (1) `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled (2) this ordering makes no sense, it is close to `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Answer (score 1):

You *seem to* want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT `working`, COUNT(DISTINCT author_id) AS `total` 
FROM `reports` 
WHERE `appid` = 379720 
GROUP BY `working` 
ORDER BY `report_id` DESC
```

Comment: Ah yes, silly me that's exactly it because I am already sorting the working with the group by. Doh.

Comment: Although, that seems to only count distinct author_id per grouping not overall.